# Replace nltk string

Tags: python, nltk

Why does replace not work with this string?

['Python \xc3\xa9 uma linguagem de programa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o de alto n\xc3\xadvel']

The above string comes from a nltk, follow the code:

```
# - * - coding: utf-8 - * -

import nltk

text = 'Python is a high-level programming language'

val = str(nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize (text))
val = val.replace('\xc3\xa9', 'é')
print val
```

Comment: Don't you want '\xc3\xa9' instead of '\ xc3 \ xa9' ? Spaces matter.

Comment: No, sorry the correct character is 'é':  Val = val.replace ('\ xc3 \ xa9', 'é')

Comment: Don't you want `text = 'Python \xc3\xa9 uma linguagem de programa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o de alto n\xc3\xadvel'` instead of `text = 'Python is a high-level programming language'`?

Comment: Best solution: Switch to Python 3, then sort it out. You're wasting your time trying to understand how Python 2 handles character encodings.

Comment: I suggest you edit your code sample so that the string `text` _actually_ contains the escape sequence. Then _test your code_ and confirm that it still has the problem you reported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val = val.replace(r'\xc3\xa9', 'é')
```

or

```
val = val.replace('\\xc3\\xa9', 'é')
```

Because `\` is a escape character.

[What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) This may be help.

Comment: Perfect! this solve may problem: val = val.replace('\\xc3\\xa9', 'é') tks vm!

Comment: @SeomisAdof, Please accept the answer if it works, tks vm.

Comment: I dont have reputation fpr this yeat